# Как построить график по массиву?

Tags: c#, график, массивы

Здравствуйте.

Есть одномерный массив.
Я его сортировал, среднее арефметическое вычислял, узнавал минимальное и максимальное значение, их суму получал.

Далее по заданию написано следующее:
По полученому массиву чисел необходимо построить график зависимости между номером элемента и значением результирующего массива. Графики должны сопровождаться соответствующими комментариями.

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять задание, то есть разобраться, каким образом требуется построить график.

Comment: Если массив, к примеру, такой:  { 0->5, 1->4, 2->7, 3->11 }( где первое число-индекс, а второе-значение), то стройте двумерный график, где высота - шкала значений, а ширина - шкала индексов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда говорят построить график зависимости между "Первое" и "Второе", то берут координатную ось и по *Х* проставляют значения "Первое", а по *Y* значения "Второе" (или наоборот, если удобнее).

То есть у вас будет ось *X* иметь значения номера элемента, а для *Y* значения элемента. Ну, на примере отсортированного по возрастанию массива:

```
array => 
  [0] = 5,
  [1] = 6,
  [2] = 8.0,
  [3] = 11.0,
  [4] = 18.0,
  [5] = 19.0
  [6] = 20.0
  [7] = 20.0
```

Получится такой постоянно возрастающий график:

[image]

P.S. Хотя не мешало бы узнать у того, кто дал такое задание, где он хочет видеть построенные графики и какие комментарии ему требуются. Очень похоже на учебное задание, которое делается только ради того, чтобы было чем занять учеников.